# How to combine 2 tables in query SQL and convert to JSON

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I have these tables

- albums (id integer, name text, year text)
- songs (id integer, title text, year text, performer text, genre text, album_id text)

This is my query

```
SELECT * 
FROM albums 
JOIN songs ON albums.id = songs.album_id 
WHERE albums.id = id
```

And this is the result of that query:

```
"albums": [
            {
                "id": "Coldplay-5KkCY8_uEaTBQqO7",
                "name": "Viva la vida",
                "year": 2008,
                "title": "Fix you",
                "performer": "Coldplay",
                "genre": "Pop",
                "album_id": "album-2008-mwlgbkMXbSqt5hlo"
            },
            {
                "id": "Coldplay-5a-QCy2W2jFTfoTR",
                "name": "Viva la vida",
                "year": 2008,
                "title": "Yellow",
                "performer": "Coldplay",
                "genre": "Pop",
                "album_id": "album-2008-mwlgbkMXbSqt5hlo"
            }
        ]
```

As you can see, the albums is there twice for the same item.

I want my result for the albums to be like this:

```
"albums": [
            {
                "id": "album-2008-mwlgbkMXbSqt5hlo",
                "name": "Viva la vida",
                "year": 2008,
                "songs": [
                   {
                     "id": "Coldplay-5KkCY8_uEaTBQqO7"
                     "title": "Fix you",
                     "year": 2008,
                     "performer": "Coldplay",
                     "genre": "Pop",
                     "album_id": "album-2008-mwlgbkMXbSqt5hlo"
                   },
                   {
                     "id": "Coldplay-5a-QCy2W2jFTfoTR"
                     "title": "Yellow",
                     "year": 2008,
                     "performer": "Coldplay",
                     "genre": "Pop",
                     "album_id": "album-2008-mwlgbkMXbSqt5hlo"
                   }
                 ]
            }
        ]
```

How can I get this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `json_agg` function and create sub-json data

```sql
SELECT
  albums.id,
  albums.name,
  albums.year,
  json_agg(songs.*) as songs
FROM 
  albums JOIN songs ON albums.id = songs.album_id 
WHERE 
  albums.id = id
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Sorry not work, the result is:
albums: [
            {
                "id": "album-2008-24YcEwsKrFvU5ial",
                "name": "Viva la vida",
                "year": 2008,
                "songs": {
           "id": "Coldplay-J9VT0ycHQQrHfOnr",
           "title": "Yellow",
              }
            },
            {
                "id": "album-2008-24YcEwsKrFvU5ial",
                "name": "Viva la vida",
                "year": 2008,
                "songs": {
          "id": "Coldplay-6TVH3PXk4JpyEqBW",
          "title": "Fix you",
              }
            },

Comment: Sorry, I made mistake, and now fix that. Please check again

Comment: GROUP BY 1,2,3, for what? and why use 1,2,3? not only 1?

Comment: These numbers reference `albums.id` (1), `albums.name` (2), `albums.year` (3) and this is shorthand for use in the group by, You can use column name and query index number both in GROUP BY